# A tensor question with a modulo group

Tags: tensor-products

[image: The question]
Im failing to see how the statement could be true, as, if we consider a=15, b=17 then we should have 15 ⊗ 5 = 17 ⊗ 3. I cant seem to get those two to be equal.

Comment: Is this from an exam?

Comment: No from an online quiz

Answer (score 1):

Writting $n \textrm{ mod } 12$ as $\bar{n}$, note that $\bar{n} = n\bar1$. Then using the bilinearity of $-\otimes-$ we get that $a \otimes \bar b$ and $b \otimes \bar a$ both are equal to $ab(1 \otimes \bar1)$.